# Apply function to a range of specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
            bucket_value  is_new_bucket
dates                                  
2019-03-07             0              1
2019-03-08             1              0
2019-03-09             2              0
2019-03-10             3              0
2019-03-11             4              0
2019-03-12             5              1
2019-03-13             6              0
2019-03-14             7              1
```

I want to apply a specific function (let’s say the mean function) to each `bucket_value` data groups where the column `is_new_bucket` is equal to zero, such that the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
            mean_values
dates             
2019-03-08     2.5
2019-03-13     6.0
```

In other words, applying a function to the consecutive rows where `is_new_bucket = 0`, which takes the `bucket_value` as input.

For instance, if I want to apply the max function, the resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
            max_values
dates             
2019-03-11     4.0
2019-03-13     6.0
```

Comment: You will probably have more luck if you specify whether this is a pandas dataframe, pyspark, etc.

Comment: I added `pandas` as an additional tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cumsum` with `filter`

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
s=df.loc[df.is_new_bucket==0].groupby(df.is_new_bucket.cumsum()).agg({'date':'first','bucket_value':['mean','max']})
s
                    date bucket_value    
                   first         mean max
is_new_bucket                            
1             2019-03-08          2.5   4
2             2019-03-13          6.0   6
```

Updated

```
df.loc[df.loc[df.is_new_bucket==0].groupby(df.is_new_bucket.cumsum())['bucket_value'].idxmax()]
        date  bucket_value  is_new_bucket
4 2019-03-11             4              0
6 2019-03-13             6              0
```

Updated2 after using the `cumsum` create the group key Newkey , you can do whatever you need , base on the groupkey

```
df['Newkey']=df.is_new_bucket.cumsum()
df
        date  bucket_value  is_new_bucket  Newkey
0 2019-03-07             0              1       1
1 2019-03-08             1              0       1
2 2019-03-09             2              0       1
3 2019-03-10             3              0       1
4 2019-03-11             4              0       1
5 2019-03-12             5              1       2
6 2019-03-13             6              0       2
7 2019-03-14             7              1       3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I really need the `max` and `mean` to have consistent dates i.e. the max value of the first bucket occurs at date `2019-03-11`, not `2019-03-08`. I guess I should have two dates then? Like `date_mean` and `date_max`?

Comment: @JejeBelfort yes , you need two

Comment: OK, but what shall I put instead of the `first` argument then for the date of the max?

Comment: @JejeBelfort check idxmax method :-)

Comment: ok thanks, however the function I need to apply is more complex than the max. What shall I do then, to extract the `date` without using `idxmax`?